# Frankfurt Card 1-Day Ticket - 24hrs or 00:00-23:59?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, germany, frankfurt

Is the ticket valid 24 hours from validation or just from 00:00 to 23:59 for exact day?

I arrive in the middle of the day and depart in the middle of the next day and I'm wondering whether 1-day ticket will be sufficient or 2-day ticket is a must.

http://www.frankfurt-tourismus.de/cms/tourismussuite/en/culture_leisure_recreation/frankfurt_card/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the answer in the website you linked:

> The one-day card is valid on the date inscribed until the end of
>   operating hours, the two-day card is valid on the day inscribed and
>   the following day until the end of operating hours.

In your case you need a two-day card.

Comment: thanks, I'm wondering how I could miss this information :o

Comment: "End of operating hours" will likely not be 00:00 to 23:59; the last ride will likely be some time past midnight.

Answer (score 1):

Since you leave mid-day, it's surely necessary to buy a 2-day-ticket. At least here in Switzerland operating hours end, when the next day's operating hours begin. In numbers: Any ticket you buy is valid the date printed on it until 5am the next morning. For further information I'd write a mail to the tourist information website. I'm sure that they will gladly help you.